# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - Houve erros de compilação. Deseja continuar e executar a última compilação bem sucedida?

Tags: c#, winforms, compilação, build

Pessoal é o seguinte: estou desenvolvendo um programa `Windows Form` para `desktop` no `C#` usando o `Visual Studio 2013`.

No entanto, as vezes quando vou clicar em `iniciar/ start` aparece uns erros de compilação do projeto sendo que ainda não dei um `build` e mesmo se eu desse, apareceria a mensagem de alerta novamente.

Toda vez que acontece isso, tenho que fechar o Visual Studio e abri-lo novamente. Isso incomoda muito porque vc vai programando só pensando que vai acontecer a mesma coisa.

Esses são os erros que copiei quando acontece isso:

**Lista de saída:**

```
Erro    12  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.    GroupManager
Erro    11  Could not copy "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.    GroupManager
Aviso   9   Could not copy "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.    GroupManager
Aviso   8   Could not copy "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.    GroupManager
Aviso   7   Could not copy "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.    GroupManager
Aviso   6   Could not copy "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.    GroupManager
Aviso   5   Could not copy "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.    GroupManager
Aviso   4   Could not copy "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.    GroupManager
Aviso   3   Could not copy "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.    GroupManager
Aviso   2   Could not copy "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.    GroupManager
Aviso   10  Could not copy "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.    GroupManager
Aviso   1   Could not copy "obj\Debug\GroupManager.exe" to "bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'bin\Debug\GroupManager.exe' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.    GroupManager
```

**Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GroupManager
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Ponto de entrada principal para o aplicativo.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

**Caminho da pasta:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver este erro?

Comment: Abra o VS como Administrador

Comment: Tem sentido, vou fazer desse modo.

Comment: Resolveu o seu problema?

Comment: aparentemente sua aplicação não está sendo devidamente finalizada, fica em execução e na próxima compilação o vs não consegue criar o arquivo novamente porque está em uso. Nos mostre sua solution, e o código do arquivo Program.cs

Comment: @LeandroAngelo usei o VS13 por um tempo, mas infelizmente o erro continua :(

Comment: @RovannLinhalis **[https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz0eL.png ]** - **[https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWVaR.png ]**

Comment: @Sérgio você pode editar sua pergunta e acrescentar as informações. Quando código, coloque-o como texto e não como imagem. Nas imagens que colocou nos comentários não vi nada de errado, e me parece uma solution simples, não deveria estar acontecendo tal erro. Tente colocar mais amostrar do seu código, principalmente se tiver alguma funcionalidade para encerrar a aplicação, como um botão sair por exemplo

Comment: @RovannLinhalis No Formulário não tem nenhum botão de encerrar a aplicação, para sair mesmo é clicando no (X) padrão da janela. Editei agora em forma de código. Dá uma olhada lá.

Comment: @Sérgio, por acaso, antivirus habilitado ? tentou desabilitá-lo ?

Answer (score 1):

Algum programa está ultilizando o arquivo compilado (.exe), ou o próprio programa está em execução. Talvez fechando a janela do programa clicando no X, não termine o processo, apenas feche a janela. Você pode usar o gerenciador de tarefas para ver os processos em execução, ou fechá-los. Ou pode ser um antivírus bloqueando o arquivo ou pasta.

Comment: Então quando iniciar o programa o arquivo compilado não deve estar em execução? É isso?

Comment: @Sérgio Isso mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Para diversas ações o Visual Studio precisa de privilégios de uma conta de Administração na máquina.

Para executá-lo como Administrador é necessário que o usuário logado tenha tais privilégios (esteja incluído no gurpo de Administradores locais da máquina).

Basta localizar o atalho do Visual Studio, clicar com o botão direito e selecionar a opção Executar `como ou Administrador` ou `Run as admninistrator`, dependendo do idioma do seu sistema operacional.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj662724.aspx)